# How can I query across multiple collections using SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Is there any way to search for particular value in all available collections in SolrCloud?

ex.I have 5 collections collection_1,collection_2,collection_3,collection_4,collection_5

each collection has common field 'app_id', I want to search all documents for 'app_id:123' on all of these collections. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can [use `CREATEALIAS` command to create a collection alias](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-createalias) that query all five collections as the same time:

```
/admin/collections?action=CREATEALIAS&name=collection_all&collections=collection_1,collection_2,collection_3,collection_4,collection_5
```

You can then query this meta-collection in the same way as you'd query any collection.